# Deploy instant oracle on Pivotal CloudFoundry for cx_Oracle

Tags: cx-oracle, cloud-foundry, instantclient, push-api

so im trying to push a python api with cx_oracle dependency which also need oracle instant client,but i couldnt found an tutorial to deploy instant client on pcf,is anybody ever do this before or have any example what should be done? appreciate it

Update:

This is the inside of my .profile

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/vcap/app/oracle/instantclient:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}
export OCI_LIB_DIR=/home/vcap/app/oracle/instantclient
export OCI_INC_DIR=/home/vcap/app/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include
export PYTHONPATH=/home/vcap/app/vendor:$PYTHONPATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: Just use the zip installer and not a package manager. Extract the files to a subfolder under your application, like `oracle/`. Install `cx-Oracle` like normal with pip. Generate requirements.txt. Add a `.profile` file to the root of your application, in it put `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/vcap/app/oracle/lib` (or path where you installed Oracle client libraries). Then push your app. The `.profile` file will adjust library search path so Oracle client libraries can be found, it runs before your app starts. Let me know if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: thanks for replying, i'm a lil confused, about the instant oracle , so i should extract it inside the project folder right? and about the .profile extension file, what is the file name? and should i add it to requirement? @DanielMikusa

Comment: Yes, extract the Oracle Instant client to a sub folder under your project. I like to call mine `oracle/` but you can name it whatever you want. `.profile` is the exact name that you need to use for the file. It's not an extension. If you're on Windows, make sure Windows isn't adding a hidden extension. The file name needs to be excactly `.profile` and needs to be in the root of your project folder, where you run `cf push`.

Comment: @DanielMikusa thanks for the tips, i already try to push it and it succeed but i see this at my app log  cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "/home/vcap/app/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so: file too short"

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the Oracle instant client libraries that you uploaded. Make sure you downloaded the 64-bit Linux instant client & extracted that to your app under the `oracle/` directory.

Comment: but it is @DanielMikusa i download it from here,the zip : [link](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html) and i extract it inside the directory, i use windows os tho, is there any other possibility?

Comment: OK, what is in your `.profile` file? It seems like if LD_LIBRARY_PATH isn't set right you can have that issue. It also seems like it need `libaio.so`, but that should be available out of the box.

Comment: @DanielMikusa so i updated my answer with my .profile, and yes the file 'libclntsh.so'  is exist but i didnt find any file named 'libaio.so'

Comment: @DanielMikusa i did it thanks daniel turns out i havent add export to my file. Is there any way to manually do pip install in pivotal? because i have scikit-surprise library that need a numpy installed first before it could be installed, and the include it in requirements.txt didn't work

Comment: No, not during staging. The python buildpack will install whatever is in your requirements.txt file. I'm not sure why that's failing without more info, kind of sounds like a different issue/question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the zip installer of the Oracle Instant Client and not a package manager.
2. Extract the files to a subfolder under your application, like `oracle/`.
3. Install `cx-Oracle` like normal with `pip`.
4. Generate `requirements.txt`.
5. Add a file with the exact name of `.profile` to the root of your application, in it put `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/vcap/app/oracle/lib` (where `/home/vcap/app` is the path to your application files and `oracle/lib` is the path to the `lib` directory beneath the folder where you extracted files in step #2).
6. Then push your app.

The `.profile` file will run before your actual application starts and it will adjust the library search path so that the Oracle client libraries can be found.

If you get the error:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "/home/vcap/app/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so: file too short"

Double check your `.profile` script and make sure that you have the correct `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` setting.