# How to deploy Node.js application with Oracle Instant client on Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: node.js, oracle, cloud-foundry, instantclient

I want to deploy my Node.js application to a Linux box with least possible manual command runs. I want to deploy it to Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF).

My application needs to connect to Oracle DB for which I am using node-oracledb and Oracle instant client.

However, I am confused how to automate downloading, unzipping and then setting up the PATH environment variable on the box for Oracle Instant Client in PCF.

Can someone suggest to me how this can be achieved?

Comment: I would suggest https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089433/1585136, except instead of steps 3 & 4 installing a Python module, install the Oracle module with `npm` and update `package.json`.

Comment: Are you able to use Docker in your CF enviroment ? Then 1 possible solution would be to use [this](https://github.com/katturajam/docker-nodejs-oracledb-instantclient) image for your `node.js` app.

Comment: @DiniFarb, yeah we ultimately, moved to PKS cluster rather than deploying in PCF directly. That made our lives easier.